# Doctrine2 trying to insert DateTime("now") into mysql datetime column

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am trying to insert date time in mysql datetime column by using following code but it is not being inserted. while isDelete working fine.

```php
/*
 * 
 * @ORM\Column (type="datetime")
 */
protected $created;   

 /** 
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function prePersist(){
    $this->created = new \DateTime("now"); 
    $this->isDelete = 0;        
}
```

Generated schema:

```
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)    | NO   | PRI |         | auto_increment |
| isDeleted | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| created   | datetime   | YES  |     |         |                |
+-----------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Any idea?

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097107/doctrine-2-0-one-to-many-many-to-one)

Comment: Can you post the result of `DESCRIBE yourtable`?

Comment: id int(11) NO PRI  auto_increment
isDeleted tinyint(4) YES  0 
created datetime YES

Comment: Onething which i just notice. If I change the datatype from datetime to timestamp in database, it start working. so problem is with format of date?

Comment: I always use `datetime` and I never encounter such issue. I don't see any reason why `datetime` wouldn't work...

Comment: Do you use $this->created = new \DateTime("now"); to insert or format the date by using old fashioned way i.e. Y-D-M

Comment: I would write: `$this->created = new \DateTime();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `*` after the `/*` above your `protected $created` property, so it's not a docblock comment and ergo isn't being parsed as an annotation. Thus, the field is not being recognized by Doctrine.

It should read:

```
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Column (type="datetime")
 */
protected $created;
```

After you fix this, run the Doctrine schema update tool.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` at the top of your class?

Probably delete seems to works but you only see the default value for a integer field (0)

Comment: I think I mentioned above in my question that isDelete is working fine. it means that I have placed that thing already :) Read the question first.

Comment: My was not working because I hadn't put HasLifecycleCallbacks() at top. Thanks a lot.